# How to build apk with Gradle offline mode in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying to build an existing android studio project with the options "use local gradle distribution" and service directory path (both pointing to local gradle files) with "offline work" enabled [File-Settings-Gradle]. But when i try to build the apk, i'm getting the error

```
Error "> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0.
     Required by: "
```

It's related to the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0' in build.gradle file. But how can I get this file and where to put it so that Android studio can build the apk offline?

Comment: yes. which android studio version are you using?

Comment: sorry, deleted by mistake. update `1.1.0` to `2.2.3`

Comment: I'm using 2.2.2

Comment: Use any version greater than 2.1.3

Comment: Offline apk build is not working on Android Studio with version 2021.3.1 Patch 1 (Dolphin).